# Using Regex to match input containing only mix of alpha numeric and special characters (without any space)

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to match input string containing  only mix of alpha numeric and special characters (without any space).

eg:

inputs :

```
1) fdg56`)(12@$5hjfgh436757))((((321\]
2) dfdgfhfghb
3) 46567657
4) df
5) &%%@erer* #@*(tyhjd4
6) sadsf5ds7f78sf
7) #29 street
8) &%%@fdgdg*#@*(dsfdsg
```

For the above eight inputs the regex should only match only 1 & 8 .it should not match input number 5 as it is having a space.
The regex which I wrote Is finding 1,8 and 5 as a match.

regex is :

```
(?=[\!\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\.\?\"\:\{\}\|\<\>\\\/]+).*
```

link:

https://regex101.com/r/0ZUuda/10

how to check and avoid matching input containing space in this regex or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Only *part* of `1` is matched because a backtick ` is not in your character set, is that desired? Or do you always want to match entire lines?

Comment: @ CertainPerformance , yes.actually it must match the all input if it is a mix of alpha numeric and special characters without any space.i need the entire line.

Comment: You don't need to escape everything inside `[]`.

Comment: You should anchor the regexp with `^` and `$` if it has to match the entire line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start at the beginning of the line:

```
^
```

Lookahead for a special character somewhere in the line:

```
(?=.*[`!@#$%^&*().?":{}|<>\\/])
```

Because you count the backtick and `#` as a special character, make sure to include them in the character set. (Most things don't need to be escaped in a character set)

Also lookahead for an alphanumeric character somewhere in the line:

```
(?=.*[a-z0-9])
```

Then match special characters and alphanumeric characters, until you get to the end of the line:

```
[`!@#$%^&*().?":{}|<>\\/\]a-z0-9]+$
```

Put it all together, and you get:

```
(?i)^(?=.*[`!@#$%^&*().?":{}|<>\\/\]])(?=.*[a-z0-9])[`!@#$%^&*().?":{}|<>\\/\]a-z0-9]+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/0ZUuda/11